# How to make sure that changes in base_url of mg_core_config_data is changed immediately

Tags: magento-1.8, core-config-data

I tried changing their values, but it is taking ages to reflect the changes made, It took nearly 4 hours for my last change. Any ways to speed up this ?

Comment: Clear the cache after changing the configuration values.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps if helps me alot to do the same thing:

1. Check the values are properly updated with the below mysql command:

> select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

1. Clear the cache (if enabled)
2. Reindex th catalog_url using shell command:

> php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url